# No Sound from headphone jack

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-8, drivers, audio

I have DELL Inspiron N5110 laptop. Using windows 8. Recently I got an issue:

The problem is, when I insert headphones and microphone into laptop, I get only microphone inserted notification. Laptop detects microphone

[image]

But no headphones. In fact, It mutes sound from it's speakers. But no sound from headphones too:

[image]

I tested headphones separately: they're working well.

I also, reinstalled windows default sound drivers and IDT High Definition Audio drivers several times. No success! The final decision is: There is no sound from headphone jack in laptop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try the latest [Windows 8 audio driver from Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-15r-n5110?driverId=CGH70&osCode=W864&fileId=3082263365)?

Comment: @techie007 no. downloading. thx for advise. will notify you about result

Comment: @techie007 Yes totally fixed my problem. Please convert this comment into answer so I can select it, sensei!]

Comment: This problem can also be caused by an external monitor installing a playback device (often when the monitor does not even have in-built speakers!). Ensure when you view the `Playback` tab that Disabled and Disconnected devices are displayed. Disable any monitor-related playback devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go grab the [latest Windows 8 Audio driver](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-15r-n5110?driverId=CGH70&osCode=W864&fileId=3082263365) from Dell's support site for your notebook model and give that a shot. :)